# Set value for amountToRelad var so it can be accessed on any method on the class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, octobercms

I'm working in a [OctoberCMS](http://www.octobercms.com) component and have some problems getting things working. Take a look at this code:

```
class Payment extends ComponentBase
{
    /**
     * This hold the amount with PayPal fee and discount applied and pass back to template
     * @var float
     */
    public $amountToReload;

    public function onAmountChange()
    {
        $amount = post('amount');

        if (empty($amount)) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('Por favor introduzca un valor.'));
        }

        $this->amountToReload = round($amount - ($amount * (float) Settings::get('ppal_fee') - (float) Settings::get('ppal_discount')), 2);

        return ['#amountToReload' => $this->amountToReload];
    }

    public function onRun()
    {
        $step = $this->param('step');
        $sandboxMode = Settings::get('sandbox_enabled');

        switch ($step) {
            case "step2":

                echo $this->amountToReload;

                $params = [
                    'username' => $sandboxMode ? Settings::get('ppal_api_username_sandbox') : Settings::get('ppal_api_username'),
                    'password' => $sandboxMode ? Settings::get('ppal_api_password_sandbox') : Settings::get('ppal_api_password'),
                    'signature' => $sandboxMode ? Settings::get('ppal_api_signature_sandbox') : Settings::get('ppal_api_signature'),
                    'testMode' => $sandboxMode,
                    'amount' => $this->amountToReload,
                    'cancelUrl' => 'www.xyz.com/returnUrl', // should point to returnUrl method on this class
                    'returnUrl' => 'www.xyz.com/cancelUrl', // should point to cancelUrl method on this class
                    'currency' => 'USD'
                ];

                $response = Omnipay::purchase($params)->send();

                if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
                    // payment was successful: update database
                    print_r($response);
                } elseif ($response->isRedirect()) {
                    // redirect to offsite payment gateway
                    return $response->getRedirectResponse();
                } else {
                    // payment failed: display message to customer
                    echo $response->getMessage();
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        $this->page['step'] = $step;
    }

    public function cancelPayment()
    {
       // handle payment cancel   
    }
}
```

If I have `$amountToReload` as public declared var on top of the class and set the value for it in `onAmountChange()` method? Then in `onRun()` method this var shouldn't keep it's set value? Why it's arriving NULL or without values? I'm newbie to Laravel coming from Symfony. What is the best way to keep the var value so I can use it through the entire class without problems?

As a second part of this post I need to generate a valid route for `cancelPayment()` method and this will go on this line:

```
'returnUrl' => 'www.xyz.com/cancelUrl', // should point to cancelUrl method on this class
```

How do I create a valid URL with, possibly, parameters, in Laravel? using URL helper? Using Route? Which one?

Comment: onRun() method is called automatically when component render on page. so you are doing some specific things when component render on page ?

Comment: @anandpatel well my idea is like a wizard, for example in the Step1 I only execute the function `onAmountChange` when the input change their value and for that I'm using the Ajax Framework, then when a user click on Step2 I should execute the first choice on the swtich as you can see in my code, maybe I can split it on `wizStep2()` and `wizStep3()` functions but using that approach I don't know, first how to pass or get the `$amountToReload` value on each function and second how to execute them, is clear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good because `amountToReload` is declared as a class property (although you might want to make that property `protected` unless you explicitly want to make it available publicly). The only issue is that the method `onAmountChange()` needs to be called before `onRun()`, for it to set the value of `amountToReload`.

As for the generating URLs the easiest way is to use `url()`:

```
url('foo/bar', $parameters = array(), $secure = null);
```

For more info check the [Laravel Helpers Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls).

Comment: And how I call the method before `onRun()`? The idea behind this is a Wizard where the first step is where I call the `onAmountChange()` when input value changes (`<input class="decimal" type="text" name="amount" placeholder="50.00" required="required" data-request="{{ __SELF__ }}::onAmountChange" data-track-input />`) so the idea is to pass that calculated amount to the code executed `onRun()` otherwise I'll need to build separately methods and I don't know how to do that, any workaround?

Comment: I haven't used OctoberCMS myself, my answer was based on a general observation of the code you posted. After having a quick look at the OctoberCMS docs, it looks to me like the `onAmountChange` method is called as a result of an AJAX call, so I think it's not being called in the same context as `onRun` which means it you can't really use the class property to pass the value around. So you'll have to pass it along with the form for it to be accessible to the `onRun` method. This is speculation on my part, you should read the docs in more detail to get accustomed to the platforms' capabilities.